# Spontaneous logout while playing a game on steam

Tags: mojave, games, steam

I was playing *Don't starve together* with a friend on Steam on my MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2019, Mojave 10.14.6) when I was spontaneously logged out of my account at exactly 11pm. The same thing occurred the following evening at precisely 11pm. I'd been playing the game in full screen mode for at over an hour on both occasions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Spontaneous logout is frequently a graphics memory issue  - the time-stamp may be a red herring. Photoshop can do this if OpenGL memory is over-subscribed - does your game use OpenGL?

Comment: Interesting thanks, how do I check if it uses OpenGL?

Comment: I don't know how you would check that from the Mac itself, but Googling "don't starve together opengl" tells me it does use it. I'd try reducing the game graphics settings, reduce shadows etc